# typescript describe object type based on field value

Tags: typescript

I have a function, that calls render function for different shapes, based on passed params and adding it's name to objects names collection:

```
export const addRenderObject = ({ type, name, data }: newRenderObject) => {
  switch(type) {
    case "box": {
      renderBox(data);
      break;
    };
    case "line": {
      renderLine(data);
      break;
    };
    // etc. shapes
    default: throw "unknown collision object type - ${type}";
  }

  objectsNamesCll.add(name);
};
```

Here is render function example:

```
const renderBox = ({ vector, height, width }: newBoxData) => {
  // box rendering
};
```

I describe params types like this:

```
type newBoxData = {
  vector: Vector;
  height: number;
  width: number;
}

type newCollisionObjectData = {
  type: "box";
  name: string;
  data: newBoxData;
} | {
  type: "line";
  name: string;
  data: newLineData;
};
```

If i call addRenderObject function with param type field as "box", i expect data field to be newBoxData type, for "line" type - data should be newLineData and so on.

**The problem** is - it's not cool to rewrite newCollisionObjectData type every time i want to add new shape. But i want to set dependency between values of type and data fields.

I tried to use generic like this:

```
type newCollisionObjectData<Type, Data> = {
  type: Type;
  name: string;
  data: Data;
}
```

It will pass an error in renderBox/renderLine functions "Argument of type 'Data' is not assignable to parameter of type 'newBoxData'".

I could use "as" operator when passing params to renderBox function, but all type checking will become useless.

Is there way to make this working and keep it simple?

Answer (score 1):

Just let create `collision-object-data.model.ts`, `box.model.ts` and `line.model.ts`:

```
export abstract class CollisionObjectData<TData extends CollisionObjInnerData> implements CollisionObjectData {
  data: TData;
  abstract render(): void;
}
```

```
export interface CollisionObjectData {
  render(): void;
}
```

```
export class Box extends CollisionObjectData<BoxData> {
  constructor(data: BoxData) {
    this.data = data;
  }
  render(): void {
    // rendering logic, using this.data...
  }
}
```

When it comes to `BoxData`, it looks like that:

```
export class BoxData implements CollisionObjInnerData {
  name: string = Box.name;
  // rest of properties...
}
```

```
export interface CollisionObjInnerData {
  name: string;
}
```

Now your `addRenderObject(...)` will be look like that:

```
export const addRenderObject = (data: CollisionObjInnerData) => {
  const collisionObjFactory = new CollisionObjDataFactory(); 
  const collisionObj: CollisionObjectData = collisionObjFactory.create(data);
  collisionObj.render();
  // objectsNamesCll.add(collisionObj.data.name);
};
```

When it comes to `CollisionObjDataFactory`:

```
export class CollisionObjDataFactory {
  create(data: CollisionObjInnerData): CollisionObjectData {
    switch(data.name) {
      case "box":
        return new Box(data);
      case "line":
        return new Line(data);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your example you are calling render on exist object, but i'm trying to create new one, based on passed params. I need to describe type with fields values dependency in passed params

Comment: Please check post now